# Linking a library via ocamlbuild/ocamlfind

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, js-of-ocaml

I have a locally pinned OPAM project called ojasmine which I want to compile as a library to be used by another project called test_tournabox (ultimately compiling to javascript). However, the compilation of test_tournabox is failing with a link error.

I compile ojasmine as follows, giving the target ojasmine.cma:

```
ocamlbuild -cflag -annot -use-ocamlfind -pkgs js_of_ocaml.log,js_of_ocaml,js_of_ocaml.syntax -syntax camlp4o ojasmine.cma
Finished, 5 targets (5 cached) in 00:00:00.
```

Then I install it like so:

```
ocamlfind install ojasmine META _build/ojasmine.cma
```

I found it strange that ojasmine.cma was not in my project directory, but instead is in the _build directory.

The output is:

```
Installed /home/laheadle/.opam/4.02.0/lib/ojasmine/ojasmine.cma
Installed /home/laheadle/.opam/4.02.0/lib/ojasmine/META
```

Next, I `cd` to my tournabox project and try to build the test suite:

```
ocamlbuild -cflag -annot -use-ocamlfind -pkgs js_of_ocaml.log,js_of_ocaml,js_of_ocaml.syntax,ojasmine -syntax camlp4o test_tournabox.byte
+ ocamlfind ocamlc -linkpkg -syntax camlp4o -package ojasmine -package js_of_ocaml.syntax -package js_of_ocaml -package js_of_ocaml.log choice.cmo util.cmo entry.cmo ttypes.cmo columns.cmo countries.cmo country_group.cmo jsutil.cmo performance_group.cmo round_group.cmo seed_group.cmo tlog.cmo tourney.cmo tournabox_lib.cmo test_tournabox.cmo -o test_tournabox.byte
```

This fails with the error:

```
Error: Error while linking test_tournabox.cmo:
Reference to undefined global `Ojasmine'
```

It seems that ojasmine.cma is not linked into the executable test_tournabox.byte. But I would expect the -linkpkg argument to ocamlfind to arrange for this. What am I missing?

Edit: Here is the META File:

```
description = "Unit Tests for javascript"
requires = "js_of_ocaml,js_of_ocaml.syntax"
version = "0.1"
```

Here is ocamlobjinfo:

```
trusty)laheadle@localhost:~/ocaml/ojasmine$ ocamlobjinfo _build/ojasmine.cma 
File _build/ojasmine.cma
Force custom: no
Extra C object files:
Extra C options:
Extra dynamically-loaded libraries:
Unit name: Ojasmine
Interfaces imported:
        ef5bf1a1d49ad28ddd8176a4f17055e1        Ojasmine
        c1a8a443b33589e4865a918c21fbbeb4        Js
        5de66fdff01f2735974be770893841e1        Pervasives
        a88f91d0f04fd66bc0bbaaf347081e95        CamlinternalFormatBasics
Uses unsafe features: no
Force link: no
```

ocamlfind sees it:

```
(trusty)laheadle@localhost:~/ocaml/ojasmine$ ocamlfind query ojasmine
/home/laheadle/.opam/4.02.0/lib/ojasmine
```

here it is:

```
(trusty)laheadle@localhost:~/ocaml/ojasmine$ ls `ocamlfind query ojasmine`
META  ojasmine.cma
```

Here is ojasmine.ml:

```
open Js

let describe (s : js_string t) (f: unit -> unit) : unit =
  Js.Unsafe.fun_call (Js.Unsafe.variable "describe")
    [| Js.Unsafe.inject s;
       Js.Unsafe.inject (Js.wrap_callback f) |]

let it (s : js_string t) (f: unit -> unit) : unit =
  Js.Unsafe.fun_call (Js.Unsafe.variable "it")
    [| Js.Unsafe.inject s;
       Js.Unsafe.inject (Js.wrap_callback f) |]

class type matcher = object
  method toBe: bool t -> unit meth
  method _not: matcher t readonly_prop
end

let expect_bool (b: bool t) : matcher t =
  Js.Unsafe.fun_call (Js.Unsafe.variable "expect") [|Js.Unsafe.inject b; |]
```

And ojasmine.mli:

```
open Js
val describe: js_string t -> (unit -> unit) -> unit

val it: js_string t -> (unit -> unit) -> unit

class type matcher = object
  method toBe: bool t -> unit meth
  method _not: matcher t readonly_prop
end

val expect_bool: bool t -> matcher t
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of the `ocamlobjinfo`, targeted on `ojasmine.cma`?

Comment: Does the package come up under ocamlfind query/list? can you load the CMA into the toplevel with ocamlfind?

Comment: A look at the META file could help. Maybe it doesn't give the good linking informations.

Comment: I have updated this with answers to all questions except the toplevel. I am looking into that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `META` file should contain an `archive` variable, so that `ocamlfind` can properly link your program with the archive, not object files. Also you need to install your `cmi` files. (And, although it is not needed for compilation, but it is a good manner to install `mli` files). So, add the following to your `META`

```
archive(byte) = "ojasmine.cma"
```

And do not forget to install `cmi`.